# How to creat WYSWYG editor in react that also parses react elements or jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx, wysiwyg

I know it's a very generic question but I want to create one web/WYSWYG editor that enables user to put html tags as well as custom components(jsx), similar to what we see in code sandbox.
Any help would be appreciated just need a direction to go. Thanks

Comment: I think you don't need one, there are some libs that you can use.

Comment: @Jamal can you point few ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some libs that you can use.
[10 Best React WYSIWYG Editor Libraries](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-react-wysiwyg-editor-libraries)

Comment: well I am looking to create an editor which supports JSX content along with HTML content. User should be able to put <CustomComponent/> in the editor. Thanks anyways